# C++ Access Violation while calling dll function

Tags: c++, exception, dll

I am actually using an unmanaged C++ DLL, and I don't have access to the .h, .cpp or .lib, but only to the .DLL.

After using `PE Explorer` and finding the function I wanted to use, here is what I get :

```
@Tdtm_Dossier@Logon$qv; Index 1310; Unmangled Borland C++ Function: qualified function Tdtm_Dossier::Logon()
```

And here is what I get from using `dumpbin` :

```
1310 11F9 00105234 @Tdtm_Dossier@Logon$qv
```

Here is the exception :

```
Unhandled Exception at 0x034B258C (modDll.dll) in functionsCpp.exe : 0xC0000005 : 
Access violation writting to 0x000000AC.
```

The code I am using to call and use this function is as follow :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*Logon)();

int main()
{
  HMODULE modDll;
  int resultLogon;
  modDll= LoadLibrary("C:\\dll\\modDll.dll");

  Logon logon;
  logon = (Logon)GetProcAddress(modDll,"@Tdtm_Dossier@Logon$qv");

  if(logon)
  {
    resultLogon = logon(); //<-- This is where I get the exception
    printf("Function has been loaded\n");
  }
  else
   // TODO: Error message

  FreeLibrary(modDll);
}
```

Since the DLL documentation doesn't give me any interesting information on how to use the function, I can't count on it.

The DLL is correctly loaded and the `GetProcAddress` does return something. I guess (but I'm not sure) that it has something to do with my `typedef`, but I can't figure out what could be the return type of this function.

Comment: @cup Yes, I've checked it and `GetProcAddress` too. Both of them aren't NULL.

Comment: Try using depends to find out what the signature is.

Comment: Are you certain about the function signature? Does it really return an `int` and take no arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this document on Borland C++ name mangling](http://www.softnco.demon.co.uk/Mangle1.txt) you might figure out that the symbol name `"@Tdtm_Dossier@Logon$qv"` represents a non-static *member* function of the class `Tdtm_Dossier`. You can't call non-static member function like normal functions, they have a hidden first argument that becomes the `this` pointer in the member function.

What's happening here is *probably* that the `Logon` member function tries to access member variables of the object instance, of which there is none, which leads to undefined behavior and a crash.

To be able to use this library you need the header file and the link library. You can't just call functions (member or not) and hope for the best.

Comment: So that means I MUST get the .h and .lib of that DLL no matter what ? There is no other way to do it I guess ? Thanks for your comment !